# Can i have grub installed on live usb?

Tags: boot, grub2, usb, live-usb

It's annoying that with grub installed on the laptop itself, everytime I don't have the Ubuntu live / persistent USB plugged in to boot into Ubuntu, i have to choose windows to boot or else i'll get sent to grub command line...
Is it possible to have grub on the usb so that it only gets activated when I want to boot ubuntu?
Thanks.

Comment: Why are you getting a Grub Rescue prompt? Did you remove your Ubuntu partition?

Comment: @wjandrea Yes I was getting a grub rescue prompt... Why? I don't know... How I fixed it? Bootrec, from win installation cd, and moved to virtual machine... Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

yea ,use gnome-disks,format disk in gpt,create main part leavin 2mb free space.run fdisk (usb) ,type `n` and then enters,then `w`.run parted (usb), `set 2 bios_grub on` (if it's 2.It's about 2mb partition  ).then deploy linux.then run this stuff `

```
mount (usbpart1) (mount dir) 
grub-mkconfig -o (...)/boot/grub/grub.cfg 
grub-install --boot-directory=(...)/boot/ (usb)
```